# Integrate $\int{ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2 }} } = \ln\left|x^2+\sqrt{{x^2}+{a^2}}\right|$

Tags: integration

$\int{ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2 }}  } = \ln\left|x^2+\sqrt{{x^2}+{a^2}}\right|$

This is one formula.  From this i can write.

$\int{ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{{(x+b)}^2 + a^2 }}  } = \ln\left|(x+b)^2+\sqrt{{(x+b)^2}+{a^2}}\right|$

Is this correct?
What if $b$ is in fraction?

Secondly is there any case  in which we divide term inside $ln$ by '$a$'

Comment: That is correct, and you can show it by substituting u = x + b

Comment: To see how the second formula hold, enough to check the change of variable $u=x+b$.

Comment: The $1^{st}$ and hence the $2^{nd}$ formula is incorrect, the integrand in $1^{st}$ integral is even, so the improper integral need to be an odd function + constant. Your RHS isn't of that form. There is a typo on your RHS, can you spot it?

Comment: No, you cannot, you forgot a constant in both the equations. Once you add it, you are good to go.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal oops, I mean indefinite integral.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal he means an indifinte integral, by the way, good you point such typo mistake achille hui (Y) .

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the correct formula is $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\ln\left|x+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}\right|+C$$

Now, substituting $x=x+b$ in the above, formula one should get 
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x+b)^2+a^2}}=\ln\left|(x+b)+\sqrt{(x+b)^2+a^2}\right|+C$$
The above formula is valid for any real value of $b$ ($b\in \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: This is not a complete answer, The OP asked if there is a case where the term inside $\ln$ is divided by  'a' .